# Closing a program using terminal from python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, applescript

I have a function that uses Xfoil to process a data file.  However I am trying to tidy up some loose ends.  As I am running OS X 10.8.2, Xfoil uses X11 (running as XQuartz) to create its graphs etc.
I would like my function to also close the XQuartz app after it has finished so I am trying:

```
os.system("""'echo osascript -e 'tell application "XQuartz" to quit'""")
```

but am having no luck.  I am using triple double-inverted commas to take the whole thing as a string and os is imported.  I believe "osascript -e 'tell application "XQuartz" to quit'" is an Apple Script which I am trying to use with the echo function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running the wrong command; you are using `echo` instead of `osascript` directly, and your single quotes *contained* in the command are not balanced (you have 3 of them).

It'll be easier to use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['osascript', '-e', 'tell application "XQuartz" to quit'])
```

Because `subprocess` takes a list of process arguments, you don't have to worry (much) about quoting.